# Example that strong convergence does not imply convergence in norm

Tags: convergence-divergence, strong-convergence

I have found an example that strong convergence does not imply convergence in norm.
Let us take $T_{n} = P_{span\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}}$ be a projection on $span\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}$ in Hilbert's space with a ortonormal base $(e_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$. Let
$$T_{n}x := \sum^n_{j=1} <x,e_{j}>e_{j}$$
where <.,.> is a scalar product. And now it is said, that from theorem about Fourier series:
$$ ||T_{n}x - Tx|| = ||T_{n}x - x|| \to 0 $$
for $n \to \infty$.

Can someone explain to me, from which theorem does it comes that it tends to zero, and why Tx = x here?

Regards

Comment: Strong convergence means convergence in norm though. Could you define these terms? Also, what is $T$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Not necessarily; Olga asks about the convergence of the operators $T_n$ to $T$ (which is the identity operator), and the notions of strong convergence and norm convergence for operators are not the same.

Comment: Indeed. Strong convergence is: $||T_{n}x - Tx|| \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ for every $x \in X$. And norm convergence is: $||T_{n} - T|| \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$

Comment: I disagree @Vladimir. Nowhere was it mentioned that there was convergence of operators, strongly or otherwise. This kind of context should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am showing that for this example, operator Tn is strongly convergence. I'm not asking about convergency, because it is obvious from $||Tnx - Tx||$ tending to zero, but from what does tending showed in the question occurs, and why the equality before it happens. Literally why 1. $||Tnx - Tx|| = ||Tnx - x||$ and second why 2. $||Tnx - x|| \to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure due to some lack of context but I suspect this is an example of the following. Given how the sequence $(T_{n})$ is set up one would expect that $(T_{n})$ converges to the identity operator $I$. And indeed for all $x\in H$ where $H$ is the Hilbert space we find that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|T_{n}x-Ix\|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|T_{n}x-x\|=0.$$
This follows from the fact that $(e_{n})$ is an orthonormal basis, so
$$x=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\langle x,e_{j}\rangle e_{j}$$
i.e.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{j=1}\langle x,e_{j}\rangle e_{j}\rightarrow x.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|T_{n}x-x\|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x-\sum^{n}_{j=1}\langle x,e_{j}\rangle e_{j}\|=0.$$

However if we consider the limit in operator norm we find
$$\|I-T_{n}\|=\sup\{\|(I-T_{n})x\|:x\in H,\|x\|\leq 1\}=\|(I-T_{n})e_{n+1}\|=1$$
So even though for all $x$ $(T_{n}x)$ strongly converges to $Ix$, $(T_{n})$ does not converge in the operator norm.

I hope this answers your questions, let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.

Comment: From the last equality after "Therefore" word, you have: $lim ||Tnx - x || = lim || x - sum ... || $ and this is equal to (from what I see) $lim \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty <x,e_{j}>e_{j} $. And why does this tends to zero?

Comment: Oh I see. Because this sum tends to x, from the upper line.

Comment: Yes. This is a fact used a lot when working with orthonormal bases.